# What can be leaked using a browser extension where one of the extensions loads JavaScript from a remote site?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, browser-extensions, browser-hijacking

Can one remotely log my IP, browser history, and saved passwords?

I think the IP should be easily done if one of the extensions load a remote JavaScript to run in my browser. I'm not sure about other stuff within the browser.

Comment: Why are you asking for these specific extensions? The threat would be the same for ***any*** browser extension.

Comment: True, but these specific extensions give users who like to install other scripts to be more productive. While other extensions is less likely to enable users to load other script （ I assume )

Comment: So then your question is "can JavaScript steal passwords from the browser?" That's easily googled and we have lots of questions like that here.

Comment: not just passwords I think since I installed a javaScript today working as it claims but looking at it code, found a remote javaScript is ”called/loaded“, then search online, people claims it as analytics, which makes me think IP is being collected already.

Comment: ... of course the IP is captured if you download something from another resource. Because that resource has to send you the thing you are downloading ... and you've already conceded that IP is exposed, leaving "browsing history" and "passwords", and since passwords are ***far*** more sensitive than browsing history, then you can simply refine your search to that ...